# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types - PHP

Tags: php, types, operand, xenforo

first time posting, usually just lurk around getting help from other answered questions, so thank you all very much for your help!

I just have a quick question. I'm installing an add-on for a forum base, and it's giving me:

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/joelwmale/public_html/forums/library/LatestThread/Controller/Public.php on line 13
```

The code at work here is:

```
<?php
class LatestThread_Controller_Public extends XFCP_LatestThread_Controller_Public
{
public function actionIndex()
{
    $response = parent::actionIndex();

    if ($response instanceof XenForo_ControllerResponse_View)
    {
        $LatestThread = LatestThread_Model_TLatestThread::LatestThreadArray();
    }

    $response->params += array('LatestThread' => $LatestThread);
    return $response;
}
}
?>
```

Line 13 is, of course:

```
        $response->params += array('LatestThread' => $LatestThread);
```

I didn't code this, my only hope is to fix this problem so i can use my forums, or else i can't use this add-on :(

thank you in advance!

Comment: To be able to use "+", `$response->params` should be an array. Check if it is not NULL. (`var_dump($response->params);`)

Answer (score 0):

What is that `$response->params` ? You can sum only numbers...you can not add array to it. If that `$response->params` is an array and you want to add another element to it you should have:

```
$response->params[] = array('LatestThread' => $LatestThread);
```

But that's just guessing. You must be more familiar with that code in order to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can't sum arrays. Try
$response->params['LatestThread'] = $LatestThread;
// OR
$response->params[] = array('LatestThread' => $LatestThread);
// OR
$response->params = array('LatestThread' => $LatestThread);
```